# pymongo sort grouped results

Tags: mongodb, pymongo, nosql

I need to group and sort by date_published some documents stored on mongodb using pymongo.
the group part went just fine :) but when I'm addding .sort() to the query it keeps failing no matter what I tried :(
here is my query:

```
db.activities.group(keyf_code,cond,{},reduce_code)
```

I want to sort by a field called "published" (timestamp)
tried to do

```
db.activities.group(keyf_code,cond,{},reduce_code).sort({"published": -1})
```

and many more variations without any success

ideas anyone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't currently do sort with group in MongoDB. You can use [MapReduce](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/MapReduce) instead which does support a sort option. There is also an enhancement request to support group with sort [here](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-1391).

Answer (score 1):

Although MongoDB doesn't do what you want, you can always use Python to do the sorting:

```
result = db.activities.group(keyf_code,cond,{},reduce_code)
result = sorted(result, key=itemgetter("published"), reverse=True)
```